# How do I show that both the additive and multiplicative groups of an infinite field are non-cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I've tried mimicking the proof in case of $\mathbb Q$ to deal with the characteristic zero case, but can't do the characteristic $p$ case. Can someone give a solution to that end?